# Intellij Reformat like in eclipse for xml files

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, intellij-idea, reformat

I work with Intellij and will use the reformat function for xml files. 
But the function dont work like in eclipse.
and i dont find the right settings to configure the formating like in eclipse( I know, that I can find the xml formatter settings in Project settings>code style>xml).

I use the eclipse formatter plugin and added in there the eclipse java formatter config file and the import order file.
But in there i cant define xml formatter preferences or?
Maybe intellij have an other plugin for xml formatter files?

had anybody the same problem, that he wants the same xml formatter settings by reformat like eclipse and can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Since IDEA users presumably don't use Eclipse, it might help to give an example showing 1) the unformatted xml, 2) the (desired) xml formatted in Eclipse and 3) the (undesired/current behavior) xml formatted in IDEA